# Storing BinarySearchTree inOrder traversal in an array

Tags: arrays, binary-search-tree, inorder

I have referred following link to see how inOrder traversal can be saved to an array [Binary Search Tree to inOrder Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050219/binary-search-tree-to-inorder-array).

My tree:

```
       100
      /  \
    50    300
   / \
  20  70
```

When first element (20) is inserted into array index value is incremented to 1. Now when control goes to fetch next node (50) index value is becoming 0.

code:

```
storeInOrder(root1,arr1,0);

private static void storeInOrder(Node root1, int[] arr1, int index) {       
    if(root1 == null){return;}

    storeInOrder(root1.left, arr1,index);       
    arr1[index++] = root1.data;
    storeInOrder(root1.right,arr1,index);
}
```

Expected output in array: 20 50 70 100 300 
 I am getting output as 100 300 0 0 0

Comment: What language are you writing this in? It appears that your index parameter is not being passed by reference.

Comment: @TeddySterne I'm writing in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the function to return the last used index and then update based on the new index.

```java
storeInOrder(root1,arr1);

private static void storeInOrder(Node root1, int[] arr1) {
    storeInOrderRecursive(root1,arr1,0);
}

private static Integer storeInOrderRecursive(Node root1, int[] arr1, int index) {       
    if(root1 == null){return index;}

    index = storeInOrderRecursive(root1.left, arr1,index);       
    arr1[index++] = root1.data;
    storeInOrderRecursive(root1.right,arr1,index);

    return index;
}
```

The wrapper function is not necessary but since you would always pass in 0 to `storeInOrderRecursive` this makes the API similar and then the return value can still be `void` for calls to `storeInOrder`.

Comment: The function `storeInOrderRecursive` declares its return type as `Integer`, but does not return a value.

Answer (score 1):

The idea to put the logic in the visiting code is correct, but you need a global index. In your implemenation, the index you modify is passed by value, which does not result in the desired behaviour, as only local copies of the value are changed. A formulation in Java could look as follows.

```
int[] iArray; // initialize with the desired size
int GlobalIndex = 0;

void Visit(Node iNode)
{
    iArray[GlobalIndex++] = iNode.Data;
}

void StoreInOrder(Node iRoot)
{       
    if(null != iRoot)
    {
        StoreInOrder(iRoot.Left);       
        Visit(iRoot);
        StoreInOrder(iRoot.Right);
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, in a more contracted form closer to the original question.

```
int[] iArray; // initialize with the desired size
int GlobalIndex = 0;

void StoreInOrder(Node iRoot)
{       
    if(null != iRoot)
    {
        StoreInOrder(iRoot.Left);
        iArray[GlobalIndex++] = iNode.Data;
        StoreInOrder(iRoot.Right);
    }
}
```

If the implementation must be as close as possible to the original version, the following version could be used. It uses a wrapper class for `int` as a replacement for call by reference, as Java does not permit call by reference for elementary data types.

```
class IntWrapper
{
    public int Value;
    public IntWrapper(int InitialValue)
    {
        Value = InitialValue;
    }
}

int[] iArray;

StoreInOrder(iRoot, iArray, new IntWrapper() )

void StoreInOrder(Node iRoot, int[] iArray, IntWrapper Index)
{
    StoreInOrder(iRoot.Left,iArray,Index);
    iArray[Index.Value++] = iNode.Data;
    StoreInOrder(iRoot.Right,iArray,Index);
}
```