# Binary Search Tree - lower() method implementation

Tags: java

I was trying to implement a `E lower(E e)` method to a BST (Binary Search Tree) data structure. It should work like this - (return the greatest element in this set strictly less than the given element, or null if there is no such element). I am stuck at this problem. Any tips?

For example, if I have a binary tree like: calling method lower(6), should return 5

5
/   
1     6

My code example (Java)

```java
public E lower(E e)
{
    if (e== null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element is null in lower(E element)");
    }
    BstNode<E> node = root;
    BstNode<E> parent = null;
    BstNode<E> ch = null;
    int cmp = c.compare(e, root.element);
    while(node != null)
    {
        if (cmp > 0)
        {
            if(node.right != null)
            {
                node = node.right;
            }
            else
                return node.element;
        }
        else
        {
            if(node.left != null)
            {
                node = node.left;
            }
            else
                ///DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to find the greatest element that is smaller than the input.

I.e. if your tree was:

```
        5
      /   \
     3     8
    / \   /
   2   4 6
          \
           7
```

You'd want the input `lower(8)` to return `7`.

You can do this via [in-order traversal](https://opendsa-server.cs.vt.edu/ODSA/Books/Everything/html/BinaryTreeTraversal.html#inorder-traversal). This will allow you to traverse the binary tree in a sorted order of elements. You can then use this to return the element before the input. One way to do this is to store the in-order traversal in an array and then print the index of the element 1 before the input's location. This will also allow you to return NULL if no such element exists.

You can find implementations of storing in-order traversals into an array [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722212/storing-binarysearchtree-inorder-traversal-in-an-array)

Comment: Im using nodes for this BST, but this could work

Answer (score 0):

You can [iterate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-iterator-for-inorder-traversal/) the BT and store the largest number that is smaller than the input.
You can also make it more efficient by not exploring a subtree that has a root that is bigger than your value or smaller than the current largest value that is smaller than the input.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

1. Let the current node be the root
2. Repeat:

   - if the current node is greater than or equal to `e` and has a left child, move left.
   - if the current node is less than `e` and has a right child, move right.
   - if the above did not produce a movement then stop looping

Then,

- if the resulting node is strictly less than `e` then it is the wanted result.  Otherwise,
- if the resulting node is exactly `e`, is not the root node, and is greater than its parent node, then its parent is the wanted result.  Otherwise
- there is no node lower than `e` in the tree.

Comment: Could you give a code example? (If you code in Java?)

Comment: @LukasJankauskas I have intentionally declined to provide code.  It's *your* homework.  What I've already given is probably more of a hint than is healthy for you.